# Edit dhcpd.conf through the WEB page

Tags: centos, dhcp, web

Good afternoon. 
Please suggest an elegant way to solve the following question:

There is a server on Linux (CentOS 6.5 x86) with dhcp/nfs/http/tftp, which is used to load the images on specialized hardware via PXE.

Was tasked to make the web page on a server with the opportunity to make changes in dhcpd.conf - add/change MAC-address.

That's the way it is happening now:

```
  group {

  next-server                     192.168.100.1;
  filename                        "pxelinux.0";
  max-lease-time                  86400;
  default-lease-time              43200;
  min-lease-time                  43200;

  host unit-dhcp-200 {
          hardware ethernet 00:0b:23:7b:f3:64;
          fixed-address 192.168.100.200;
  }

  host unit-dhcp-201 {
          hardware ethernet 00:0b:28:fc:71:e3;
          fixed-address 192.168.100.201;
  }

  }
```

Please help with ideas, or solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Before this gets closed I'll just suggest that rather than showing/editing `dhcpd.conf` somehow the OMAPI interface to the dhcp server (assuming it is ISC's) may be the better interface to it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OMAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say :

- Code your own web page (e.g using PHP, it will not be so difficult).

or

- Consider something like [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) that can (among other things)
  manage `dhcpd` config and address reservation using a web interface.

By the way, [product recommendations are off-topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). What you are asking is a kind of disguised product recommendation...